# How to adjust height of right div using css

Tags: css

I have 2 columns of divs (left and right) contained in the parent div. I want the parent div height automatically adjusts when either left or right div height expand. The problem I have now is that the height of parent div just expands when the left expand, it does not work for the right. I have height:auto for all divs.

Are there anyone have solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by `float` for example

```
<div class="parent" style="float:left">
   <div class="child" style="float:left"></div>
    <div class="child" style="float:left"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: That... is not the solution, you are not even clearing the floats, and you're floating too many elements, what if the parent div is meant to be centered? Also, to "properly" use only left floats, explicit width should be given.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `float` to move the right div to the right side. Floats do not automatically adjust the parents height, you must add the following code right before the end of the parent `div`.

```
<br style="clear:both;" />
```

This will mark the end of all floats on the same level.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably floating your divs to keep them next to each other. By doing so, you 'remove these divs from the flow', i.e. the parent does not take them as content anymore.

You can 'by-pass' this effect by giving `overflow: hidden` to the parent or by adding a clear div.

Example w/ overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/LJTGh/

Important CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    height: auto;
    width: 77%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden; /*THIS IS IMPORTANT */
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

**OR**

Example w/ clear: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/LJTGh/1/

Important CSS:

```
.clear {clear: both;}
```

​
The first option needs a line more of CSS, the second one a line more of HTML and a line more of CSS.

Comment: Did you mean you write something there?

Comment: @DamonGant Write something where?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I am not using any float in my css. If I have overflow: hidden, it hides the content which I really want to show.

Comment: @TranNgocTrung Can you then post an example on something like www.jsfiddle.com?